# Traefik internal only traffic

Tags: traefik

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 Docker host running Traefik and Free-ipa server, i want to use trafek to block extranal access to free-ips server but allow internal ranges.

is this possible?

Thanks
Mo

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker's network to isolate your environment, for exemple,

```
services:
  traefik:
    networks:
      - traefik-net

  free-ipa:
    networks:
      - internal-net

  others:
    networks:
      - traefik-net
      - internal-net
```

Here, `others` can access `free-ipa` just by using `free-ipa` as dns name, and it's accessible by traefik as well. `traefik` can't see `free-ipa` because they are not in the same network.

Comment: Ok that fixes part of the puzle, but the ports 443 still clash on Traefik & freeipa, I need for the public facing sites, and intenal via accessible only names suche as https://domain/freeipa. Freeipa breaks if you expose/port map on anything else except 443.